# How to obtain RGB values for matplotlib color schemes?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I get these example cdict values (https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/pylab_examples/custom_cmap.html):

```
cdict = {'red':   ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
               (0.5,  1.0, 1.0),
               (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)),

     'green': ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
               (0.25, 0.0, 0.0),
               (0.75, 1.0, 1.0),
               (1.0,  1.0, 1.0)),

     'blue':  ((0.0,  0.0, 0.0),
               (0.5,  0.0, 0.0),
               (1.0,  1.0, 1.0))}
```

for the bwr color scheme (https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html) in matplotlib?

Comment: `bwr` is just blue white red. Maybe you want to tell what you need those for, I suspect that this is a [xyproblem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: I want t create a custom color scheme similar to bwr but with a wider range for the middle white part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the question, the colors for the "bwr" colormap can be obtained via

```
import matplotlib.cm
print(matplotlib.cm.datad["bwr"])
```

which prints

```
((0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

and that is simply `["blue", "white", "red"]`.

This may not be too useful for the actual application though.
To create a colormap with a wider range of white in the middle, best create the colormap from a list of colors, and possibly their respective values.

To this end, the [`LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.html#matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list) method can be used.

```
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = [(0, "blue"), (0.4, "white"), (0.6, "white"), (1, "red")]
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("bwwr", colors)
```

The numbers are between 0 and 1, need to be ascending and denote the "position" of that respecitive color. The above would create a colormap with a gradient from blue to white between 0 and 0.4, then all white between 0.4 and 0.6, then a gradient from white to red between 0.6 and 1.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

colors = [(0, "blue"), (0.4, "white"), (0.6, "white"), (1, "red")]
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("bwwr", colors)

a = np.arange(0,100).reshape(10,10)

fig, (ax,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(7,3))
im = ax.imshow(a, cmap="bwr")
fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
im2 = ax2.imshow(a, cmap=cmap)
fig.colorbar(im2, ax=ax2)

ax.set_title("bwr")
ax2.set_title("bwwr")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: A simple and elegant approach! Thank you.